# Why do icns files created on Lion not work on Leopard and before?

Tags: macos, icons, backwards-compatibility

If I compose an `icns` icon file on an OSX Lion machine, either using the built in Icon Composer or with [makeicns](http://amnoid.de/icns/makeicns.html), the largest two icon sizes (512 and 256 pixels) are not visible/available on a Leopard machine. Why is this, and is there a way around it?

Comment: Please specify the exact version of the Xcode install you're using as well as the version of Icon Composer.

Comment: I am not using Xcode (although the installed version is 4.2). The version of Icon Composer is 2.2 (134).